# MySQL Peformance tuning

Tags: mysql

We are migrating data from a proprietary system to Redmine. The app server and db server are two separate boxes. MySQL is hosted on an t3 large AWS EC2 matching  (2 VPU and 8 GB RAM).

The system has 250 Users, 1200 projects, 32000 Issues and 180000 time logs.

Taking a spent time report using the following query takes more than 90 seconds.

```
use pmsdb;
SELECT  `time_entries`.`id` AS t0_r0, `time_entries`.`project_id` AS t0_r1,
        `time_entries`.`author_id` AS t0_r2, `time_entries`.`user_id` AS t0_r3,
        `time_entries`.`issue_id` AS t0_r4, `time_entries`.`hours` AS t0_r5,
        `time_entries`.`comments` AS t0_r6, `time_entries`.`activity_id` AS t0_r7,
        `time_entries`.`spent_on` AS t0_r8, `time_entries`.`tyear` AS t0_r9,
        `time_entries`.`tmonth` AS t0_r10, `time_entries`.`tweek` AS t0_r11,
        `time_entries`.`created_on` AS t0_r12, `time_entries`.`updated_on` AS t0_r13,
        `enumerations`.`id` AS t1_r0, `enumerations`.`name` AS t1_r1,
        `enumerations`.`position` AS t1_r2, `enumerations`.`is_default` AS t1_r3,
        `enumerations`.`type` AS t1_r4, `enumerations`.`active` AS t1_r5,
        `enumerations`.`project_id` AS t1_r6, `enumerations`.`parent_id` AS t1_r7,
        `enumerations`.`position_name` AS t1_r8
    FROM  `time_entries`
    INNER JOIN  `projects`  ON `projects`.`id` = `time_entries`.`project_id`
    INNER JOIN  `users`  ON `users`.`id` = `time_entries`.`user_id`
      AND  `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'Person', 'AnonymousUser')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `enumerations`  ON `enumerations`.`id` = `time_entries`.`activity_id`
      AND  `enumerations`.`type` = 'TimeEntryActivity'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  issues  ON issues.id = time_entries.issue_id
      AND  (projects.status <> 9
              AND  EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT  1 AS one
                    FROM  enabled_modules em
                    WHERE  em.project_id = projects.id
                      AND  em.name='issue_tracking')
           )
    WHERE  (projects.status <> 9
              AND  EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT  1 AS one
                    FROM  enabled_modules em
                    WHERE  em.project_id = projects.id
                      AND  em.name='time_tracking')
           )
    ORDER BY  time_entries.spent_on DESC, time_entries.created_on DESC,
        time_entries.id ASC
    LIMIT  25 OFFSET 0
```

The Redmine application hangs / time outs because of long execution time. How to lower the execution time?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes:

```
time_entries:  INDEX(project_id, spent_on, created_on, id)
time_entries:  INDEX(            spent_on, created_on, id) -- see below
enabled_modules:  INDEX(name, project_id)  -- in this order
```

I suspect the complexity of the last `ON` is not really what you wanted.  Perhaps you want `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` in both cases?

What version of MySQL are you using?

```
ORDER BY  spent_on DESC, created_on DESC, id ASC
```

has a mixture of `DESC` and `ASC`.  This is available only in MySQL 8.0 and only if you match the directions in the `INDEX`.

Alternatively, changing the direction of `id` this would probably suffice:

```
ORDER BY  spent_on DESC, created_on DESC, id DESC
```

(It may or may not actually use the corresponding `INDEX`.)

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  I suspect it will start with `enabled_modules`, `projects`, `time_entries` (in order).